# How to fix The user ID and password are invalid error in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, navision

I am using c# to get the result from Navision webservice. When i am using defaultcredential = true i am getting the below exception:

```
    System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException
   "The user ID and password are invalid. Try again."
```

If i am using networkcredential with domain user name and password its working fine.

```
   WarehousePickdetail.WS_WarehousePickdetail_Service Service = new WarehousePickdetail.WS_WarehousePickdetail_Service();
            Service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            //Service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strUser, strPwd);
            WarehousePickdetail.WS_WarehousePickdetail[] list = Service.ReadMultiple(null, null, 0);
            string result;
            result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
            this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            this.Context.Response.Write(result);
```

Comment: As error shows,  `WarehousePickdetail` needs credentials to proceed.

Comment: I have referred the code here:    https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freddyk/2010/01/19/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from-c-using-web-reference/